# How to Concatenate Variable Strings in Closures

Tags: javascript, closures, concatenation

As you will see I have a function where I am practicing **closures** with a function which returns another function. It works just fine except that when the function interviewQuestion(job) is called in the 5 examples below, the *else* condition only prints the last of he call fuctions and I want to know how to make them both print. I have the following code:

```js
function interviewQuestion(job) {
  return function(name) {
    if (job === 'painter') {
      return document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = name + ' how do you paint images?';
    } else if (job === 'salesman') {
      return document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = name + ' how do you sale things?';
    } else if (job === 'singer') {
      return document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = name + ' how do you sing?';
    } else {
      var string = '';
      string = document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = name + ' what position are you interested in?' + '<br>';
      return string;
    }
  }
}

//Function is called:
interviewQuestion('painter')('Lucy');
interviewQuestion('salesman')('Richard');
interviewQuestion('singer')('Juliana');
/*else*/
interviewQuestion('window washer')('Pepe');
/*else*/
interviewQuestion('bootshiner')('Bob');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Section 5: Advanced JavaScript: Objects and Functions</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Section 5: Advanced JavaScript: Objects and Functions</h1>

  <h3>Practice on Closures:</h3>

  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>
  <p id="demo3"></p>
  <p id="demo0"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I fix my return statement for the *else* part? I want, if there is more than 1 call for that part of the function to be able to get all results printed one after the other.

As of now with 5 calls to the function I only get 4 results:

- Lucy how do you paint images?
- Richard how do you sale things?
- Karla how do you sing?
- Bob what position are you interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite the former value of the element. To get both string, you could just add both new values to it with `+=`.

I changed all outputs to ones with a line break.

Then I changed the `return` statement to perfom an early exit, which means you need no `else` statements, because of the `return` statement, which exits the function.

```js
function interviewQuestion(job) {
    return function(name) {
        if (job === 'painter') {
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += name + ' how do you paint images?' + '<br>';
            return;
        }

        if (job === 'salesman') {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += name + ' how do you sale things?' + '<br>';
            return;
        }

        if (job === 'singer') {
            document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML += name + ' how do you sing?' + '<br>';
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML += name + ' what position are you interested in?' + '<br>';
    };
}

interviewQuestion('painter')('Lucy');
interviewQuestion('salesman')('Richard');
interviewQuestion('singer')('Juliana');
interviewQuestion('window washer')('Pepe');
interviewQuestion('bootshiner')('Bob');
```

```html
<h1>Section 5: Advanced JavaScript: Objects and Functions</h1>
<h3>Practice on Closures:</h3>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo0"></p>
```

Just for completenes, you could move all information into an object and define a default function for unknown jobs.

```js
function interviewQuestion(job) {
    var data = {
            painter: name => document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += name + ' how do you paint images?' + '<br>',
            painter: name => document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += name + ' how do you paint images?' + '<br>',
            salesman: name => document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += name + ' how do you sale things?' + '<br>',
            singer: name => document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML += name + ' how do you sing?' + '<br>',
            default: name => document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML += name + ' what position are you interested in?' + '<br>'
         };

    return data[job] || data.default;
}

interviewQuestion('painter')('Lucy');
interviewQuestion('salesman')('Richard');
interviewQuestion('singer')('Juliana');
interviewQuestion('window washer')('Pepe');
interviewQuestion('bootshiner')('Bob');
```

```html
<h1>Section 5: Advanced JavaScript: Objects and Functions</h1>
<h3>Practice on Closures:</h3>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo0"></p>
```

Comment: I knew it would be something very simple I just could not figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I see that in your correction you included += to all conditions as it also applies. And it looks cleaner. ;))